# Multidimensional array inside checkboxes

Tags: python, django

Is there a way so i can set a html checkbox with a bidimensional array, something like this:

```
<input type=checkbox name=message[group1][1] value=1>
```

If yes,

1) how should I do to accomplish that in case the example I wrote is wrong?

2) how could I access those elements from a request handler in django?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use such checkboxes names, ultimately it's just a string. To get all elements on server side you could generate checkboxes names and get its values. Like this:

```
def multi(request):
    arr = []
    for x in range(1, 6):
        cur_row = []
        arr.append(cur_row)

        for y in range(1, 6):
            curr_cell = bool(request.POST.get('message[group%d][%d]' % (x, y)))
            row.append(curr_cell)

    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

But server needs to know what ranges will come to process all checkboxes. I set 1..5 range for example.

PS. Is `value` attribute as valid for checkboxes? What about `checked` attribute?

Comment: thanks demalexx! i'll try to implement your suggestions and let you know how it turns out! The value attribute was just for a sake of example.